# Junit not working on SBT in Play! Framework project on Intellij 14

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, playframework-2.0, sbt

i'm having some troubles with tests in Intellij, i created a new project with

```
activator new my-project
```

then opened that projected with intellij, i marked all boxes for SBT to auto-download and create empty folders, etc.

Well after the project is opened and loaded all SBT stuff i have some errors.

First with versions:

```
SBT project import
     [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
     [warn]  * org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:(4.0.1, 4.3.4)
     [warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:(18.0, 16.0.1)
     [warn]  * junit:junit:(4.12, 4.11)
     [warn]  * org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:(4.0.1, 4.3.2)
     [warn]  * commons-logging:commons-logging:(1.1.1, 1.1.3)
     [warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.3)
     [warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.3)
```

then with the junit

[image: SBT Root and Junit]

i looked up and there is some solutions to the vesion problem, but they didn't work for me and i have nothing about the junit thing.

Tests work on terminal but i can't have markdown in intellij

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed some conflicting dependencies with some of the libraries.

To work around the JUnit conflict, you can add:

```
"junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
```

to the *libraryDependencies* in **build.sbt**.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, i installed the new version of intellij and apparently it's gone.